# Replace characters

Tags: php, regex

I have a lot of strings of special characters.
I want to replace all special characters with character `"-"`
The characters do not need to be replaced as `"-"` are `"A-Za-z0-9"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this :

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9-]/", "-", $yourString);
```

---

**Resources :**

- [php.net - `preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 3):

Pretty straight forward.

```
$text = preg_replace('~[^0-9a-z]~i', '-', $text);
```

**Extra Information**

See [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for further information.

The `^` inside the Character Class `[]` at the start basically says, "Match any character except the ones following it".